# modified k-mean algorithm for an image clustering

Tags: matlab, k-means

i m trying to implement the modified k_mean algorithm for an image clustering i.e very much similar to k-mean. Difference is only of new center calculation.

Actually i have initialize the cluster centers, calculated distance between pixels and centers, now based on minimum distance i'll have to assign the pixels to clusters but here problem is that how to assign and store pixels to clusters, How would i know which pixel belongs to which cluster for new center calculation ?

Comment: Are you asking a programming question here?  If so, you need to provide more detail.  If you are asking a statistics question (something that is related to the theory of k-means clustering), you should ask on [statistics.se].

Comment: sorry my mistake i forgot. Yeah it's a programming question and i want help in matlab.

Comment: Right now, this isn't a good programming question because you're asking roughly for a guide to how to do k-means clustering, which is too broad for here.  If you want help with code, give some example data for the point at which you need help, and show what you're trying to figure out, and what programming framework it needs to fit in.

Comment: ok actually these are the steps i am following of modified k-mean for clustering of  RGB image :    step 1- define set of D dimension data, step 2- define the number 'k' of clusters, step 3- define the clustering metric 'M' , while metric M is not stable " compute distance dkj = ||xj – zk||2 for each k, j where 1 ≤ k ≤ K and 1 ≤ j ≤ N, and determine members of new K subsets based upon minimum distance to zk for 1 ≤ k ≤ K;compute new center zk for 1 ≤ k ≤ K "
compute 'M'

Comment: within-cluster sum of squares is the metric for algorithm convergence , i have image pixels as the data for clustering and i have chosen randomly the number of clusters as 10 , i have calculated the distance between pixels and defined initial cluster centers . Now, i want help in assigning the pixels to clusters based on the minimum distance i have calculated and also i do wanna know how would i know which pixel belongs to which cluster

Comment: If you want to take a look at an existing kmeans implementation that already works and is very fast, see my post here: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post17_divquant_clustering/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Restating what you have already said, you want to run k-means where your training examples are pixels each of which have 3 features (*Red*,*Green*,*Blue*).  I'll mention in passing, though it looks like you already have decided on something, to define the distance norm by first normalizing the RGB data from 0 to 1.0 rather than say 0 to 16 or 0 to 255, so that you can compare results irrespective of the color depth.

You should order the pixels 1..m, and store them in a *m* x *3* matrix ***X*** (see below) m = *width* x *height*. How you assign each pixel to a row of ***X*** if up to you, so arbitrarily set pixel at image position (x,y) to row y*width + x.

Now you simply need need to use an additional *m* x *1* index vector ***idx*** to keep track of which pixel belongs to which centroid.

```
idx = zeros(size(X,1), 1);

for i = 1:size(X,1)
   minNormSq = 0;
   for j = 1:K
      normSq = sum((X(i,:) .- centroids(j,:)).^2);
      if j == 1 || normSq < minNormSq
         minNormSq = normSq;
         idx(i) = j;
      end
   end
end
```

Later you can [assign a array to a boolean condition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html) when computing the new centroid values.

```
for j = 1:K
   inclusion = (idx == j);
   centroids(j,:) = inclusion'*X;
   centroids(j,:) = centroids(j,:)/sum(inclusion);
end
```

Comment: thank you for this code its useful for me but please do tell me what do you mean by last line of your second paragraph ? actually i am reshaping  the image matrix into matrix of [1.....m] where m is row*col is this wrong ???? if i wont store it in m*3 matrix please help

Comment: @lavi Typically the training set is stored in 1 big matrix to aid vectorization where samples are the rows and the features are the columns.  So in this problem ***X*** will be m x 3.  There's no requirement that you assign pixels in any particular order, you just have to be consistent.

Comment: this is what i have done to get X  of size m*3  im=imread('D:\l.jpg');
[row col fet]=size(im);
im1=double(im);
m=row*col;
X=reshape(im1,m,fet);   is this oky ??? when i am writing code for what you told me for arbitrarily setting pixel at image position (x,y) to row y*width + x code is not working showing the error so please tell me after reshaping is this necessary to code ??